# Removing ManyToMany relationship with PrimaryKeyRelatedField in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models like this:

```
Tags(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    value = models.TextField()


Note(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Where Tags are used to categorise Notes just like StackOverflow questions here. When clients create/update Notes I want them to be able to send a list of Tag ids in order to associate them. This works well. When they fetch the Note, I want the Tags in full, not just a list of IDs. So I subclassed `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and overrode `to_representation`:

```
class RelatedTagsField(PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            'id': value.id,
            'key': value.key,
            'value': value.value
        }


class NoteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    tags = RelatedTagsField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
                            many=True,
                            required=False,
                            allow_empty=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'
```

This works well when creating Notes and when adding Tags by sending a PATCH containing the Tag IDs in a list, but it doesn't work when sending an empty list to untag a Note. DRF just doesn't do anything at all (the `QueryDict` is empty, so is `validated_data`).

Here is an unit test to illustrate the problem:

```
class TaggedNoteTestCase(APITestCase):
    # setUpTestData omitted
    def test_update(self):
        # create a tag
        response = self.client.post(
            f'/api/tags/',
            {
                'key': 'mytag',
                'value': 'bla'
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        tag_id = response.data['id']
        response = self.client.get('/api/tags/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), num_tags + 1)

        # create a note with the tag
        response = self.client.post(
            '/api/notes/',
            {
                'key': 'testkey',
                'value': 'blabla',
                'tags': [tag_id]
            })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        self.assertGreater(len(response.data), 0)
        note_id = response.data['id']

        # check tag
        response = self.client.get(f'/api/notes/{note_id}/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['tags'][0]['id'], tag_id)

        # create another tag
        response = self.client.post(
            f'/api/tags/',
            {
                'key': 'mytag2',
                'value': 'bla'
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        self.assertGreater(len(response.data), 0)
        tag2_id = response.data['id']

        # update note to add 2nd tag
        response = self.client.patch(
            f'/api/notes/{note_id}/',
            {
                'tags': [tag_id, tag2_id]
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertGreater(len(response.data), 0)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data['tags']), 2)

        # remove tags
        response = self.client.patch(
            f'/api/notes/{note_id}/',
            data={
                'tags': []
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertGreater(len(response.data), 0)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data['tags']), 0)
        # ^^^^^^^^^ this fails, number of tags is still 2!
```

I expect DRF to use the list of IDs to set the Tags associated with the Note. This works when creating a Note with Tags using `POST`, and it works when adding or removing the Tag association of an existing Note by sending a list of IDs with `PATCH`. But it doesn't work when I want to remove all Tag association by sending an empty list of Tag IDs with `PATCH`.

What am I doing wrong? Why can I use the list of IDs to set the ManyToMany relationship to add and change relations but not to remove them completely by passing an empty list?

Comment: You want to update a Note and send empty list for tags, removes tags related to Note?

Comment: PATCH requests are supposed to contain partial data. When you submit an empty list, the expected result would not be to delete all entries on the server. If you want to delete entries, the appropriate http method would be DELETE.

Comment: @MohammadAli Yes, exactly

Comment: @HåkenLid I don't want to delete the Note, I want to remove the tags association on the note

Comment: Yes, but since deletion typically is irreversible, it's generally a bad idea to implicitly delete related entries as a result of a PATCH request. If you want to delete an entry, you should require a explicit delete command. One way is to send a DELETE request to a `/api/tags/{id}/` endpoint (for individual deletion).  If you want bulk deletion, you should implement a custom override. For example `data={'DELETE_tags': [42, 33]}`.

Comment: @HåkenLid Sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't want to delete the Tags, I want to delete the association(s) between the Notes and the Tags.

Comment: Ok. In that case, this seems unexpected. Note that there might be a difference between a multipart patch (from the browsable api html form, and possibly from the test client) and an json patch (ajax call). An empty value in the multipart form might be ignored in a PATCH. But in a json request, the `[]` value should clear entries from the m2m relation. Make sure your test client sends `application/json` in the patch.

Comment: The reason for this difference, I think, is that it's not possible to tell the difference between what's meant as an empty list and what's meant as a omitted field when you submit a html form. With json, you can simply omit one key when you want to submit a partial update.

Comment: If you are using the drf test client, use `client.patch(url, data, format='json')` to submit your patch requests as `application/json` (the default is `multipart/form-data`)
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#using-the-format-argument

Comment: Setting `format='json'` makes it work as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set `format='json'` in the API test client. Thanks to Håken Lid for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is solved, but I want to add about solving a similar problem with when sending requests via python requests

```
response = requests.patch(url="http://exmpl/smth/", data={"subscribers": []})
```

If you are sending requests this way and have encountered this problem then replace the data argument with the json argument

```
response = requests.patch(url="http://exmpl/smth/", json={"subscribers": []})
```